# Android Tablet camera does not focus when using QFIELD

Tags: qgis, qfield

I am using a Lenovo TB-X704L tablet, Android 7.1.1 with the latest QFIELD app installed. I prepared in QGIS 3.4 a tree survey project with a GPKG point layer, packed it for QFIELD and transferred the data to the tablet. The project opens just fine in QFIELD, with all the edit functions available. The layer table has a field called 'image' in which QFIELD puts the name of the photo I wish to take of the tree. When I click the camera button to take a picture, the camera only focusses very close by. Everything further then 1 meter away is out of focus. When I use the native camera function, the program crashes (which does not surprise me as this function is unstable on recent Android versions). The camera itself is ok, when I take a picture outside QFIELD, all is fine.

If this sounds familiar to anyone, what can I do?

Comment: Bug >https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/571 ("With the successful crowdfunding the implementation of the new camera functionality is on it's way.")