# High quality photos using QFIELD

Tags: qfield, photos

i'd like to take high quality photos with my tablet/smartphone during a survey with QFIELD. 
But i have some issues because with the camera used by the App, i cannot zoom in/out and the quality is bad, while using the native android camera of the smartphone QFIELD crashes.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I believe this is coming soon https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341761/android-tablet-camera-does-not-focus-when-using-qfield

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QField version 1.4, to be released soon, fixed the native camera problem. A few more days and it will be available.